# How can I access the Office 365 Group Connectors preview?

Tags: office365connectors

The developer preview for Office 365 Group Connectors was announced at Connect(). How do I access this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch your browser in InPrivate or Incognito mode, then go to the following URL:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/owa/#path=/mail&EnableConnectorDevPreview=true
```

The `EnableConnectorDevPreview` parameter is case-sensitive.